# Comparing 2 dates to give 3 outcomes.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compare

I have a need for the changing of the headertext image in ASP.NET tab container to different colours. For Example if today is `23/04/2014` and the `ImageUrl="~/icons/vwicn114.gif"` of my tab ( with the `ID` "FireTraffic" ) and I need to update a record in my SQLserver in 2 days time , I need to change the ImageURL. so think of it as a TrafficLight system. here is a snippet of code to help understand:

```
        connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand("Select TOP 1 [Due Date] From FireTest Order By [Due Date] Desc", connection)
    Dim DueDate As String = command.ExecuteScalar()

    Dim Mycommand As New SqlCommand("Select TOP 1 [Date] From FireTest Order By [Date] Desc", connection)
    Mycommand = command.ExecuteScalar()

        connection.Close()
```

So my code will be something like :

```
  If mycommand "is 1 day more than" DueDate then firetraffic.ImageURL=Red  
  If mycommand "is 3 days or less than" DueDate then firetraffic.ImageURL=Yellow
    End If 
   End If
```

I just don't know what I should be putting into the spaces which obviously aren't code , any guidance to an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ? :

```
Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim dueDate As DateTime = .....

Dim result = ""

'If overdue for one day or more'
If (d1 - dueDate).Days >= 1 Then
    result = "red"
'If 3 days or more to due date'
ElseIf (dueDate - d1).Days <= 3 Then
    result = "yellow"
Else : result = "green"
End If
```

Comment: You need to convert your value that you are assigning to dueDate to a Date by using either `Date.Parse(dueDate)` or `CDate(dueDate)` the latter of which if deprecated.